# Running SonarQube in TeamCity causes a break with a stack dump when Build Breaker is used

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1, teamcity-9.0

We run SonarQube in a TeamCity build using the msbuild.sonar.runner, which in turn runs the sonar runner.
To break the build when a quality gate files, we have been trying to use the Build Breaker plugin. When there is no issue the build runs as expected, but 
when there is a Build Break error, it is followed by an execution error:

```
[08:14:32][Step 3/4] ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
[08:14:32][Step 3/4] org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4] Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Alert thresholds have been hit (1 times).
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.api.batch.BuildBreaker.fail(BuildBreaker.java:34)
[08:14:32][Step 3/4]    at org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker.analyseMeasures(AlertBreaker.java:57)
```

I am sure this is not expected behavior, but it prevents us from deploying these builds to effectively monitor SonarQube issues

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Build*Breaker* plugin does - it breaks your build. :)

The 'Caused by' message tells you why: Alert thresholds have been hit (1 times).